# Opening up the options list and adding 2 buttons, one to a little alert with about us and a exit

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

I'm building an mobile application with JQuery Mobile and I found a very big bug.. 
If I press the back button on the phone it's just like clicking on the back arrow on the browser. I would like to click on the button surrounded by red on this picture: [image: androidphone]

I want it to when I click it shows the 2 options which are "About" and "Exit". I saw some stuff online about the exit button but couldnt get any to work and I also tried to find something on the jquerymobile docs but no success..
Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To listen to those events you will have to use PhoneGap if you are building non native app.

Comment: I'm using PhoneGap just to build the apk file, do I have to import it to my project like jquery and use its events?

Comment: Yes, if you see the demo app provide by them(phonegap), they have specifically demonstrated what you require.(They have handled the menu button.)

Comment: I'll check it out tomorrow, then Ill give you some feedback, thanks!